# Meteorjs - which protocol is it using?

Tags: comet, meteor, channel, bayeux

I'm looking at MeteorJS at the moment and I was wondering which protocol they are using on their channels.
Is it Bayeux ? their own ?
I wasn't able to find easy accessible infos on their website ( I mean apart from digging in the source code)

thanx.

Comment: Saw somewhere mention its DDP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into this blog post: http://www.meteor.com/blog/2012/03/21/introducing-ddp

they are using DPP as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Thx Andreas. Now that I know what I'm looking for, found this here: [Documentation or code details on Meteor's DDP pub/sub protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128430/documentation-or-code-details-on-meteors-ddp-pub-sub-protocol)